# Produce Country flag using Emo::ji in R in gt table

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, gt

[image: Output produced from code, still no flag]I am trying to get country flags using library(emo) in R markdown document as part of gt table. Below is my code, I see ASCII code of countries rather than flag when I knit the document not sure what's wrong

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(gt)
    library(emo)

 
   df <-data.frame(
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                    Country = c("Health sciences",
                                "Physical sciences","Engineering",
                                "Computer science, maths","% of women inventores"),
                 Japan = c(0.24, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.08),
                 Chile = c(0.43, 0.23, 0.22, 0.16, 0.19),
        United.Kingdom = c(0.45, 0.21, 0.22, 0.21, 0.12),
         United.States = c(0.46, 0.2, 0.22, 0.22, 0.14),
                Mexico = c(0.46, 0.25, 0.26, 0.22, 0.18),
               Denmark = c(0.47, 0.22, 0.23, 0.18, 0.13),
                  EU28 = c(0.48, 0.25, 0.25, 0.22, 0.12),
                France = c(0.48, 0.24, 0.25, 0.22, 0.17),
                Canada = c(0.49, 0.21, 0.22, 0.22, 0.13),
             Australia = c(0.5, 0.23, 0.25, 0.24, 0.12),
                Brazil = c(0.57, 0.33, 0.32, 0.24, 0.19),
              Portugal = c(0.57, 0.37, 0.36, 0.27, 0.26)
         )
```

Code to produce gt table still not flag in output

```
df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
   cols_label(Country="Department" ,
              Japan=paste0("Japan",emo::ji("jp")),
              Chile=paste0(emo::ji("chile")),
              United.Kingdom=paste0(emo::ji("uk")),
              United.States=paste0(emo::ji("us")),
              Mexico=paste0(emo::ji("mexico")),
              Denmark=paste0(emo::ji("denmark")),
              EU28=paste0(emo::ji("eu")),
              France=paste0(emo::ji("france")),
              Canada=paste0(emo::ji("canada")),
              Australia=paste0(emo::ji("australia")),
              Brazil=paste0(emo::ji("brazil")),
              Portugal=paste0(emo::ji("portugal")))
```

Comment: It seems that emoji rendering differs from OS to OS. Some display flags, some two letters country abbreviation (see issue https://github.com/hadley/emo/issues/59). I'm on windows and see small "JP" for Japan.

Comment: Thanks, anyway to get rid of this ?

Comment: Hard using emoji but you can replace them with images by providing html labels (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit overkill but works!

You can use URI encoded image in an html col label. For that you need to provision png icons for each country you need to display. Here I named them following their abbreviated name

```
library(base64enc)

flagAsIMG <- function(country_code) {
  img <- paste0("data:image/png;base64,", base64encode(paste0(country_code, ".png")))
  paste0("<img src='", img, "'/>")
}

library(gt)
library(magrittr)

gt(data.frame(japan=1)) %>%
  cols_label(japan=html("Japan", flagAsIMG("jp"))
```